# Webdeploy a ReactJS web application to IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, webdeploy

We have developed a ReactJS web application and we want to host this application on IIS. The application successfully runs on IIS. Now, it is time to upgrade the application. Instead of manually copying the files to IIS folder, we want to simplify the deployment process.

How can we deploy the build package that is generated using command `npm run build` onto IIS web site using WebDeploy protocol?

(Note: IIS has already been configured to accept and successfully executes WebDeploy requests, such as Visual Studio MVC project outputs.)

Answer (score 1):

It may be difficult to implement it, because web deploy often requires visual studio to package the application, which is different from the direct build of reactJS.

More deployment of ReactJS is to copy to remote IIS after the build is completed.If you insist on using web deploy, first you need to combine it with visual studio, packing the ReactJS after building.Then use [powershell to deploy the package onto the remote server](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy).
[image]

My preferred method is to use [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/). It is simple and easy to use, especially for the subsequent upgrade and deployment needs of your application. It can be deployed remotely, and it is also very convenient to upgrade and iterate after deployment.

[Azure Pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/)